# shell how to apply a function to all the files in the directory and copy in another folder the results?

Tags: shell

```
zcat 7days/src_file1.gz | head | ./addsubnets.py rndc_subnets.cfg |
    gzip -9c > 7days_subnet/src_file1.gz
```

I have this shell function. It applies an operation to the file in  the `7days` folder and saves it in the `7days_subnet` folder.   How can I repeat this operations for all the files in `7days`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for file in 7days/*; do
    file=${file#7days/}

    zcat 7days/"$file" | head | ./addsubnets.py rndc_subnets.cfg |
        gzip -9c > 7days_subnet/"$file"
done
```